# How does iTunes gain access to a passcode-locked iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, usb, password

Recently I witnessed how *iTunes*, which is linked to a certain iPhone may unlock it's first screen - the one which requires a *password*.

I also know of a few tools which may mimic this effect;

I`m curious about how this mechanism works. Does apple hold some sort of a *"master key"* that can be transferred via a USB device? Is that a part of the operating system, *iTunes* or some of those other tools? Is that a known weakness, or a feature? How do those tools (generally) work?

Now, this question is for academic purposes only. Please do not take it anywhere else, that's not what it's meant for.

Comment: Please try to limit a topic to one question. Regarding "Is that a known weakness or a feature", that is highly subjective.

Comment: @tubedogg I think there should be a clear answer to that question if you're familier with this. If there's, for example, a master key - it's probably intended. However if they do so by, let's say, some weird buffer overflow of some sort - then it's probably a weakness.

Comment: I think I can say with 100% certainty that Apple does not rely on buffer overflows to make their software work.

Comment: @tubedogg lol, I'm pretty sure so myself. If so, you probably say they wouldn't explicitly exploit a weakness in one of their own products... Then it's probably a feature, and not a weakness. Any idea what kind of feature is it, though? How does it work? I couldn't find anything useful on a quick googling session.

Comment: I think the chance of finding documentation by Apple on 'how to get past a lock screen' is less than unlikely.

Comment: @Tetsujin I do not think there is a documentation, but considering the amount of tools there are out there - Somebody should know. I'm hoping that somebody will come across this question, sooner or later.